# Continuity of a function at a point

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Provide an example of each or state why it is impossible to find such a function

```
f(x) and g(x) are not continuous at 0, but f(x)+g(x) and f(x)g(x) are continuous at 0.

f(x) is not continuous at 0, but f(x) + 1/f(x) is.
```

Moreover, if we want to negate a statement like above, we can use the definition of continuity; however, if we suspect the statement to be correct, is there a more systematic way to come up with examples that fit the criteria?

Comment: In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: [This might be helpful.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first one:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
1,&\text{if }x=0\\
0,&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

$$g(x)=\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if }x=0\\
1,&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

As f(x) + g(x) is then 1 everywhere and f(x)g(x) is 0 everywhere.

For the second one:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
1/2,&\text{if }x=0\\
2,&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Then f(x) + 1/f(x) = 5/2 everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

For the first one:
$$f(x)=|\operatorname{floor}(x)|$$
$$g(x)=\operatorname{ceil}(x)$$